Google Cloud GKE dashboard cluttered with deployment patch events from Strimzi Kafka operator - how to get rid of this?
I'm using the Strimzi Kafka operator in my k8s cluster. It's working fine and Kafka is up and running. But the operator reconciliation is triggering a change in the deployment every two minutes, which, according to this discussion, is perfectly fine.
The problem is, this event is now completly cluttering every pre-defined dashboard Google is offering, making them nearly unusable. Here is an example screenshot:

Every two minutes there is an audit event alert in every timeseries, making them barely readable and also hiding "real" events.
Is there a general way to get rid of this, without having to filter out this event manually in each and every dashboard?

Shouldn't it be possible to change the log level for Kafka operator?
